# Flutter SliverPersistentHeader is causing "bottom overflow when scroll"

Tags: flutter, overflow, flutter-sliver

i have a `SliverPersistentHeader` that causes `bottom overflowed` when user scrolls the screen.

[image: Bottom overflowed]

How can i fix it?

```
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: false,
          delegate: DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate(
            maxHeight: 256,
            minHeight: 186,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                _topo(context, grupo),
                _infoGrupo(context, grupo),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // TODO: Lista do grupo 
        SliverFillViewport(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('TODO... A construir'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

// .....

```
class DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget child;
  final double maxHeight;
  final double minHeight;

  const DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate({
    @required this.child,
    this.maxHeight = 250,
    this.minHeight = 80,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return child;
  }

  // @override
  // bool shouldRebuild(DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => maxHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by wrapping the `DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate` Column child with a `SingleChildScrollView´ with`NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` **physics**.

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: false,
      delegate: DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate(
        maxHeight: 256,
        minHeight: 186,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            _topo(context, grupo),
            _infoGrupo(context, grupo),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // TODO: Lista do grupo 
    // ...
  ],
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you please update your code? it is missing and not showing the final result- thank you!

Comment: @romaneso The author explained the solution. To be explicit, I updated the code with the fix in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The complete fix is:

```
 return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: false,
          delegate: DynamicSliverHeaderDelegate(
            maxHeight: 256,
            minHeight: 186,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _topo(context, grupo),
                  _infoGrupo(context, grupo),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // TODO: Lista do grupo
        // ...
      ],
    );
   }
```